# unicode regular expressions c++

Tags: c++, regex, boost, unicode, boost-regex

I want to match the word **"février"** or any other month by using regular expression.

**Regular expression:**

> ^(JANVIER|FEVRIER|MARS|AVRIL|MAI|JUIN|JUILLET|AOUT|SEPTEMBRE|OCTOBRE|NOVEMBRE|DECEMBRE|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|JUN|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|[jJ]anvier|[Ff]évrier|[mM]ars|[aA]vril|[mM]ai|[jJ]uin|[jJ]uillet|[aA]o[éû]t|aout|[sS]eptembre|[oO]ctobre|[nN]ovembre|[dD][eé]cembre)$

---

### Problem

The problem is that I cannot match the words that contain unicode letters: **à,é,è** etc.
I found on the following website: [Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) that the unicode value of `é` is `\u00E9`. Can i integrate this value in the regular expression? and how can I use unicode values in regular expressions.

---

```
void returnValue(string pattern)
{
    bool x = false;
    const boost::regex e("février");
    x = boost::regex_search(pattern.c_str(),e);
    if(x){ cout <<"found"<<endl; }
}
```

Comment: @bits_international boost. Ah no I am using the boost library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match a unicode with boost::regex. There are two ways to do it.

1. Rely on wchar_t if your platform's wchar_t can hold Unicode characters and your platform's C/C++ runtime correctly handles wide character constants. (this has few pitfalls, not suggested, read about this in the link I provided)
2. Use a Unicode aware regular expression type (boost::u32regex). Boost has to be configured to enable this via [Building With Unicode and ICU Support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html#boost_regex.install.building_with_unicode_and_icu_support)

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/unicode.html

Comment: I found the following example on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/non_std_strings/icu/unicode_iter.htmlDo u know what this regular expressions means? const char* re = "([[:Sc:]][[:Cf:][:Cc:][:Z*:]]*)?"

Comment: thease are ICU regexes, you need <boost/regex/icu.hpp>, but in order to use this header you will need the ICU library, and you will need to have built the Boost.Regex library with ICU support enabled.