# std::regex_match with characters é è à

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-studio-2017, std

I want for example to consider "ram" , "rém" , "rèm" and "ràm" as a valid input, so i do this:

```
std::string ss = "rém";
bool valid = std::regex_match(ss, std::regex("r[aéèà]m"));
```

but in this case 'valid' returns false, is there something special with the characters é, è and à ? Should i modify the regex expression ?
Thanks

Comment: Likely a bug in the implementation. Can you try the same on boost regex?

Comment: What is the encoding used? `std::string` doesn't support UTF... Prefer `wstring`.

Comment: I get `true` after running this code in VS2017.

Comment: This might be a dupe but I'm hesitant to hammer it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23932970/10077

Comment: @FredLarson I think it is the problem... I have another link on the same problem. You can close.

Comment: Try declaring `std::wstring ss = L"rém"` and then use `std::wcout << std::regex_match(ss, std::wregex(L"r[aéèà]m"));`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right, i convert to std::wstring and it works. In fact, in my project i have the string and the regex as an UTF8 std::string input , so é for example is encoded as Ã© and that's why we need to convert to UTF16 before doing std::regex_match

Comment: Please let me know if the solutions in the duplicate links work for you, or if your question should be reopened.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i think that it's not exactly the same. the first link use boost::regex and the second is about using unicode representation (\\u0080 for example) in the regex instead of the latin represent which not  easy to read and understand whithout using the doc

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but i think there is another issue, whith the same regex "r[aéèà]m", if  the input is "rmm" so the regex_match return false which is ok, but then if i put "rMm" i get True which is not ok, is there something to add for uppercase characters ?

Comment: With `L"rMm"` as input, I get `0` as output, so no match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make use of `std::wstring` to define the string and then use `std::wregex` to actually run regex on Unicode strings:

```
std::wstring ss = L"rém";
std::wcout << std::regex_match(ss, std::wregex(L"r[aéèà]m"));
// => 1, there is a match
```